# Why does my Spring Boot application serve correctly web content locally but then I get 503 on Heroku?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I would like to try Heroku and - to do that - I want to host a really simply Spring Boot Application that serve a single JSP page on /.

I can perfectly access the page when running the application locally, but on Heroku I get the following error:

```
2019-01-29T18:20:10.128285+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=mignemisportfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=f6e168b9-1bdc-4e9d-92e6-99cc9891ce95 fwd="80.110.86.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

You can find the code in my [repo](https://github.com/Giovarco/Portfolio).

Comment: This is deployment problem, not source code. Can you tell about deployment process from source code to Heroku?

Comment: - I created a new app starting with the wizard, from here: https://dashboard.heroku.com/new-app
- I created no pipeline
- I've used Gitlab a deployment method
- I enabled automatic deploys from master
- The build process had no errors
- I got the message "Your app was successfully deployed."
- I clicked "View"
- / is opened automatically, but I get this error message: "Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command"

Comment: Does it help? Do you need other details?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running applications with embedded web server on Heroku instead of running WAR applications. If you change packaging to `jar` and use embedded Tomcat, Heroku will autoconfigure server port and if you add addon to SQL database it will also set up all environment variables.

If you need to stay with WAR (I see you're using JSP - Thymyleaf is actually way nicer than JSP) - as far as I know you need to add `webapp-runner` to your project as explained here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner